# Filter an object object in javascript (filter or reduce?)

Tags: javascript, object, filter, reduce

What the best practice to filter or reduce an object? I would have done this via for-loop and created a new array but understand that you can do it somehow via filter property in JavaScript?

```
var myObject = [
  {dimensions: [451, 255], margins: [0, 2, 0, 29]}, 
  {dimensions: [222, 390], margins: [0, 5, 0, 37]},
  {dimensions: [333, 390], margins: [0, 8, 0, 37]}
];
```

I would like to filter out separately the dimensions first, property and margins second and fourth, property in a array to have:

```
var dimension = [ 451, 222, 333 ];
var margins = [ 2, 29, 5, 37, 8, 37 ];
```

Also if I filter an object and update these variables, is there a way to map them back? Or should I have it as below to map afterwards:

```
var dimension = [ a: 451, b: 222, c: 333];
var margins = [ a: [2, 29], b : [5, 37], c: [8, 37] ];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `reduce`:

```
var myObject = [{
  dimensions: [451, 255],
  margins: [0, 2, 0, 29]
}, {
  dimensions: [222, 390],
  margins: [0, 5, 0, 37]
}, {
  dimensions: [333, 390],
  margins: [0, 8, 0, 37]
}];


var results = myObject.reduce(function(acc, item) {
  acc.dimensions.push(item.dimensions[0]);
  acc.margins.push(item.margins[1], item.margins[3]);
  return acc;
}, { dimensions: [], margins: [] });

console.log(results); // {dimensions: Array[3], margins: Array[6]}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9ynez03c/

To map back to `myObject`:

```
var dimensions = results.dimensions;
var margins = results.margins;

var updateMyObject = function() {
  myObject.forEach(function(item, i) {
    item.dimensions[0] = dimensions[i];
    item.margins[1] = margins[i * 2];
    item.margins[3] = margins[i * 2 + 1];
  })
};
updateMyObject();
```

This is very clunky.  I'm not sure how you're using this data, but something tells me that you should be using an object in the first place and then accessing/updating properties as needed instead of creating additional arrays.

New fiddle with update: https://jsfiddle.net/adrice727/g01s80qf/

Comment: Adrice, if I update dimension array and margins array, how would you map them back to  myObject. Or directly how would you update the myObject ?

Answer (score 0):

Filtering works fine, if you only want a subset of an array which meets some conditions (like all numbers greater than 5 from an array of arbitrary numbers). In your case I would definitely go for a loop.

```js
var myObject = [
  {dimensions: [451, 255], margins: [0, 2, 0, 29]}, 
  {dimensions: [222, 390], margins: [0, 5, 0, 37]},
  {dimensions: [333, 390], margins: [0, 8, 0, 37]}
]

var dimensions = [];
var margins = [];

myObject.forEach(function(item) {
  dimensions.push(item.dimensions[0]);
  margins.push(item.margins[1]);
  margins.push(item.margins[3]);

  // or by using concat():
  // dimensions = dimensions.push(item.dimensions[0]);
  // margins = margins.concat([item.margins[1], item.margins[3]]);
});

console.log("dimensions:", dimensions);
console.log("margins:", margins);
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback but my also concern is to get the code as short as possible and I can seem how people get them done via filter and very short.

Comment: Okay. Well, in my opinion, your main concern should be to keep the code most understandable and not only to be very short. Using functions which are not common, like `reduce` might not lead to more understandable code.